# Help with gigabyte lan drivers

Tags: lan

I got the gigabyte GA-970A-ds3p motherboard and I can not use a wired connection. Is there any lan drivers i can download for ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Is it the onboard Ethernet port, or is it a separate card?

Comment: It is an onboard ethernet port.

Comment: I still need help.

Answer (score 0):

Old post but if people are looking around for help this may help.  Take a look at this thread: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2188370   “GA-970A-DS3P revision 1 no usb 3.0”

> Here is my updated fix
>
> First enable iommu in the uefi by restarting your computer and
>   pressing delete to enter the uefi
>
> plug your usb mouse, keyboard and thumbdrive in usb 2 ports.
>
> save and exit the uefi
>
> Then In Ubuntu:
>
> press Ctrl+Alt+T to open up a terminal
>
> run the following command: sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
>
> Only edit the empty quotes in this line to read:
>   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="iommu=soft"
>
> save changes to grub and exit gedit and the terminal
>
> Open up a new terminal with ctrl+alt+t
>
> run the following command: sudo update-grub
>
> then exit the terminal using this command: exit
>
> Restart your computer press delete to get back into the uefi
>
> Disable iommu in bios, load optimized defaults and restart.
>
> usb, 2.0 usb 3.0 and networking all work now in Ubuntu, and disabling
>   iommu in bios may also help improve your boot times.